# How should I design a new function according to OOP?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, design-patterns

Say I need to add some function `foo` that takes an instance of type `A` and produces an instance of type `B` (assuming `A` and `B` are interfaces). In object-oriented design, what are the design limitations of either of the following designs?

Design 1:

```
class A {
  foo(): B { /* … */ }
}
```

Design 2:

```
class B {
  static foo(a: A): B { /* … */ }
}
```

Comment: This post is asking multiple questions at the same time; could you please [edit] to clearly indicate which single question is your primary question and whose answer would constitute an answer to the post? (Otherwise the post risks being closed as needing focus) Also note that if you want it to be a "how should I do this" or "are there reasons to prefer this to that", you should probably be careful to ask it in a way that invites objective responses instead of opinions.  (Otherwise the post risks being closed as seeking opinions).

Comment: @PeterSeliger While `foo` was just a placeholder, I intentionally didn't choose an explicit name like `create...` because I think it depends on the operation, especially in DDD. For example, `User.signIn(Credentials creds)` looks more correct to me than `User.create(Credentials creds)`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Well my question isn't about naming, but about the design limitations of something like `User.signIn(Credentials creds) -> User` vs. `creds.signIn() -> User` in terms of extensibility. The tradeoffs, if any, aren't obvious to me.

Comment: @DennisKats ... Good, because all my comments so far are within the context of the _"factory function"_ pattern and not at all about naming. But unsurprisingly already example code with an expressive naming gives the answer. In terms of modeling what reads most natural and with the best meaning ?.. `User.signIn(Credentials creds)` or `creds.signIn()` .., especially with both functions returning a `User` instance. Hint ... _"one does sign in with credentials"_ versus _"specific credentials do (themself) sign in"_

Comment: Both are technically the factory method pattern, no? In this case, `User.signIn(Credentials creds)` certainly reads more naturally, but I'm not sold there are no design limitations between them. For instance, `creds.signIn()` enables a subclass of `Credentials` to easily return a subclass of `User`; that seems slightly less trivial with the other design. Plus my original motivation for this question is based on the array grouping proposal for JavaScript, in which there was initially a lot more support for a prototype extension (arr.groupBy(...)) than for a static method (Map.groupBy(...)).

Answer (score 1):

From the technical point of view there's no difference.

What OOP can suggest is that in a concrete case (where `A`, `B` and `foo` means something specific) you can refer to the SOLID/GRASP set of recommendations and check if there's a rule judging one approach over the other.

In OOP, it's a matter of **responsibilities**.

Take three examples:

1. `A` is `Order`, `B` is `ProcessingResult` and `foo` is `Place` and you are just implementing a domain model of your DDD approach. The natural choice for `Place` is `Order`

   ```
   public class Order 
   {
      public ProcessingResult Place() { ... }
   }
   ```
2. `A` is an auxiliary class (`Parameters`), `B` is a domain class and `foo` is a factory method of a the class. The natural choice for a factory method is the class it's supposed to create

   ```
   public class B
   {
      public static B Create( Parameters parameters ) { ... }
   }
   ```

(however, a separate factory class would also be correct here, it all depends on a content)

3. `A` is `FooUseCaseParameters`, `B` is `FooUseCaseResult` and `foo` is `Execute` and you are just designing a primary port for your hexagonal architecture. The natural choice in this case is a new class (`C`) which would be the `FooUseCase`:

   ```
   public class FooUseCase
   {
      public FooUseCaseResult Execute( FooUseCaseParameters useCase ) { ... }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But aside from the naturalness of each approach, do they have limitations in terms of extensibility and scalability?

Comment: If all three examples cover all three possible cases and all come from practical, real-life scenarios then assume that there are no limitations behind any of these.